# How i can get the numbers on the left and the right of the given element?

Tags: php, arrays, string, pagination, numbers

Given a string:

```
$pages = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
```

Create a function that gets the numbers on the left and the right of the given element.
I expect this ouputs:

```
pagination(1); // array('prev' => null, 'next' => 2);
pagination(2); // array('prev' => 1, 'next' => 3);
pagination(6); // array('prev' => 5, 'next' => null);
```

I don't want to use explode() i want to use only
only use string manipulation functions.
This it's was i tried but is 8 apear ... i need to see, the 5 between ','

```
<?php
$number = "5";
$pages = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
$x = strpos($pages, $number);

echo $x;

?>
```

Comment: `explode()` is a string manipulation function...

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use explode as otherwise it will be very complex to get it right when you have more than 9 numbers.

Comment: Indeed but this can be a 500 word <p> for example.

Comment: Smells a lot like homework or basic programming exam, especially the "I don't want to use explode()" part... just saying...

Comment: [`strtok`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) is probably what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but I think this could give you an idea.

This doesnt work for numbers >= 10.

```
function get_near_elems($number = 5)
 {
        $pages = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
        $x = strpos($pages, $number);

        if($x == 0)
          return array('prev' => null, 'next' => $pages[$x]);
        else if($x == (strlen($pages) - 1))
          return array('prev' => $pages[$x - 2], 'next' => null);
        else
             return array('prev' => $pages[$x - 2], 'next' => $pages[$x + 2]);
}
```

Since this looks like homework, I suggest you take something you see here and modify it.

Comment: `$pages[$x - 1]` (same for +1) will result in a "," being select as that is the next character in the string. So it would have to be -2/+2 AND this won't work for numbers above 9...

Comment: Yeah, I corrected it. He hasn't specified whether it has to work for numbers > 10.

Comment: Yep, sorry overlap. Still will be broken with numbers above 9 because that will be two characters long then.

Comment: Right, if numbers are never > 9 it's just fine. Just don't see a reason not to use an array.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function similar to the following one, just need to make sure the pages variable is accessible in the function.

```
function getPreviousAndNext($number)
{
    $location = strpos($pages, number);

    $previous = ($number > 0 ? substr($pages, ($location - strlen($number - 1)), strlen($number - 1) + 1) : null);
    $next = ($number == strlen($pages) - 1 ? null : substr($pages, ($location + strlen($number + 1)) + 1, strlen($number + 1));

    return [
        "previous" => $first,
        "next" => $last
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`explode()` would be helpful but given the constraints:

> mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )

gives the position of the index in string, try removing ',' by using [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
// removes ',' from string
str_replace(',', '', $pages);
```

which results in "123456" then `strpos($pages, $number)` will gives you the index of the index position 4. Given validations ( bounds check ) ie. `> 0` and `< strlen(..)`, you can get the previous and next with -1 and +1.

Hope this helps.